# How should I distribute an iOS SDK in the form of a static library?

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk, distribution, static-libraries

I'm currently compiling a static library for iOS, let's call it libMySDK.a.  I copy any header files that the end user will need and put them into a folder with libMySDK.a.  This folder can be dragged into a new Xcode project and everything works as expected if I set the -all_load linker flag in the build settings of the new project (under 'Other Linker Flags').

I have never distributed a static library - is a folder with a few header files and a .a file what you would expect to receive if you wanted to use MySDK?

Comment: I'd expect to receive the source code. Why not just distribute that, rather than a compiled library?

Comment: I am keeping the source closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openfeint provides its framework as a Static Framework. We can use the framework as a Framework from iOS SDK.

- "Add OpenFeint as a framework" in [Readme for OpenFeint iOS SDK 2.10.1](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-for-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-10-1/)

Please take a look at [github - Eskipol/OpenFeint-iOS-Framework](https://github.com/Eskipol/OpenFeint-iOS-Framework). Open OpenFeint project and dive into the "OpenFeint-iOS" target. It has 'Build static lib', 'Build universal lib', 'Copy Headers' and 'Copy Resources' phases. These phases have shell script to create a Static Framework. It would help you to distribute your static library.

**EDITED:**

The essential is in the shell script for 'Build universal lib' phase. Create framework directory properly (Versions/A/Headers and Resources), create universal binary from the compiled static libraries, copy headers and the universal binary, and create symbolic links properly.

```
# Create framework directory structure.
rm -rf "${FRAMEWORK}" &>/dev/null
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A/Headers"
mkdir -p "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A/Resources"

# Generate universal binary from desktop, device, and simulator builds.
lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}" -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_PATH}"

# Move files to appropriate locations in framework paths.
cp "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${FRAMEWORK}/Versions/A"
cd "${FRAMEWORK}"
ln -sf "A" "Versions/Current"
ln -sf "Versions/Current/Headers" "Headers"
ln -sf "Versions/Current/Resources" "Resources"
ln -sf "Versions/Current/${PRODUCT_NAME}" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
```

Comment: Thanks Kazuki!  I'm marking this as the answer.  In case anyone finds this via Google, it seems my original approach is acceptable too.  The Flurry SDK is delivered with a single .a file and a FlurryAPI.h header.  I think the static framework approach has some advantages regarding versioning, but I'm not sure what those are yet!